# A few Bitshifting questions!

Tags: c++

So `int` in Arduino is 2 bytes, which could technically hold up to a value of 65535. However, the MSB is used as a sign bit, so now we have -32,768 to 32,767. So it's a *signed integer*, easy stuff. While I was messing around with bitshifting I ran across something interesting. If I do the following code:

```
int a = 1023 << 6;  // 1023 = 0b0000001111111111
Serial.println(a, BIN);
```

it returns a ridiculous number, 11111111111111111111111111000000, which is 4 bytes. I know this is some error with bit shifting into the signed bit, because if I do

```
int a = 1023 << 5;  // equals 111111111100000 as expected
```

It works just fine. **Question 1:** What is happening here? Where is that number coming from?

So I got smart (so I thought) and was like okay, if I need more bytes, then I'll just use `long`. So I tried the following code:

```
long a = 1023 << 6;
Serial.println(a, BIN);
```

I figured I'd have 3 "extra" bytes to shift my number into. However, the same number is returned. **Question 2:** What is happening?

**Question 3:** What is the order of operations with bitshifting?

```
Wire.write(CMD_VDR | PD_NPD | voltageLevel >> 6);
```

This code I wrote produces the correct result. However, what is the order of operations? Is it just left to right? Putting `voltageLevel >> 6` in parenthesis does not change the output. *It's working fine but I want to know why!*

Thanks!

Comment: Your third part was tacked on after I'd started answering and it is largely unrelated to the rest of it. You can probably sort it out by looking at [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: research  `sign extend`

Comment: Please do not put multiple unrelated questions in one post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

timemage provided an excellent answer to your first question (upvoted!).
Let me try to answer the subsequent ones:

> ```cpp
> long a = 1023 << 6;
> ```

Here you are evaluating `1023 << 6`, then assigning the result to a
`long`. It is important to realize that the C++ rules for evaluating an
expression do not depend on what you are going to do later with the
result. Given that `1023` is an `int` constant, the expression has the
type `int` and is evaluated as such. The result is then undefined
behavior, which just happens, because [you are unlucky](https://www.nayuki.io/page/undefined-behavior-in-c-and-cplusplus-programs), to give
the expected value, i.e. −64.

Assigning −64 to a `long` converts the type while preserving the value.
This is [sign extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) at work. As explained by timemage,
`println(long, int)` casts the value to `unsigned long`, hence the
result you see.

> What is the order of operations
> [in the expression `CMD_VDR | PD_NPD | voltageLevel >> 6`]?

The shift has higher precedence than the bitwise OR. The expression is
thus equivalent to

```cpp
CMD_VDR | PD_NPD | (voltageLevel >> 6)
```

C.f. [C++ Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: Thank you for sharing the precedence list! That's quite helpful.

Comment: Well, technically I did attempt to answer the second one. It just wasn't as clear as how you'd put it. The storage I was talking about was the intermediate result of the right-hand side, which applies to *both* of their expressions. But, since you've written this I'm just going to vote yours up rather than try to clarify what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

> So `int` in Arduino is 2 bytes

This is not true in the general case, for what it's worth. It is true of the AVR based Arduinos though, which I'll assume are in use below.

Strictly speaking, when you do `int a = 1023 << 6;` with a 16-bit integer, all bets are off, because you're already in undefined behaviour. 1023 is type `int` right hand side is expected to be of type `int` and trying to store something that won't actually fit in a signed integer is undefined.

But for the moment, lets just say it does roughly what you expect with the bit pattern, like it would for an unsigned type. You've produced the bit representation for a signed 16-bit integer with the value -64.

You're calling the `println(int, int)` [here](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/1.8.6/cores/arduino/Print.cpp#L77).
It's in turn calling `println(long, int)` [here](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/1.8.6/cores/arduino/Print.cpp#L87-L101). It is only handling `signed`ness for base 10. So, you are just forwarding your -64 value to `printNumber` [here](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/1.8.6/cores/arduino/Print.cpp#L203), which handle `unsigned long` values (which may have been prefixed by `-` for base 10).

So you are converting a -64 into an `unsigned long`. Conversion to unsigned types reduce modulo their maximum value plus 1.  The 32-bit `unsigned long` maximum is 0xFFFFFFFF, with one added you get 0x100000000. In other words, you're ultimately printing 0x100000000 - 64, which is the number you're seeing.

`1023 << 5` does not overflow the 16-bit signed int. Does not result in a negative number (again if we're being charitable about undefined behavior) and so you see different result.

Comment: "It is true of the AVR based Arduinos though," - (Not calling you out on this, but) for completeness it's worth mentioning that `int` is 2-bytes on an AVR Arduino _with the gcc compiler_ because that is what the implementers of that compiler chose for it to do. Another C/C++ compiler on the same hardware might do things differently. Which is to say, the width of `int` is not a function of the hardware but of the compiler. The width of `int` is usually chosen as the native word size of that hardware, but on an AVR, that would be 8 bits which isn't nearly as useful as 16.

Comment: @JRobert Yeah, I didn't know how far into the weeds they wanted to go. It actually wouldn't be compliant to have a 8-bit `int` type an account of it not meeting the minimum required range, though gcc will let you do it with `-mint8`.  But yeah, a compliant compiler could target the AVR and do any number of things like that. E.g. you could make all of the integer types 64bit, even the `char` type and have `CHAR_BIT` be 64. Again, it's difficult to know where to stop with it.

Comment: I could put something like *"The actual range of the `int` type is determined by the compiler rather than hardware. It is subject to the standards requirements to the extent that the compiler is trying to adhere a standard, which is partly under the control of what options have been specified to the compiler. The intention is normally to have it follow the standard and where possible to have it follow some notion of the natural integer size of the underlying architecture."* or shorter *"without going into the details it is ultimately the compiler that determines the `int` type size."*

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response

Comment: @timemage: Fair enough! I do tend to see the details....